# Rails generating views from admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I'm developing a simple CMS, where admin should be able to configure main menu (item positions, adding new items, deleting others, etc) from admin panel. So I've figured out that the best way, is not just creating new table in database but dynamically create view, and that's my problem. In my opinion using database for that is not necessary as the menu will be displayed frequently (it's on every page) and admin won't change it too often.

I want Rails to create view (code) in for ex. views/layouts/_main_menu.html.haml including whatever admin will want to put there. Is there any gem for that or should I do it with some kind of ruby script? Does anybody were doing something like that and can support me with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in production you'd have to restart the server to reload the new views ... so I don't think it's the best way to take ...

I'd personally store everything in the DB and cache everything properly (fragment caching with proper expiration, take a look here : http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works)

This way, if menus/pages are not edited, they'll never be reloaded from SQL

Comment: Thanks for you answer Anthony. But.. what if I create some html file in public directory? Wouldn't it be faster? I'll check out this caching. Thank you :)

Comment: I guess you could store some html in the public directory and read/write in your app code but ... sounds a bit like a hack ... plus storing in SQL will be cheap anyway (guess it'll be in a small table), and you can make it lightning fast with caching ... therefore I wouldn't give me the trouble of reading/writing custom files :p

Comment: So, I will do it as it is done in other CMSes. Thanks a lot! :)